# How to load test login having Sitefinity - Azure AD B2C Authentication oauth2 with JMeter

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, jmeter, azure-ad-b2c, sitefinity

There are multiple requests being passed in signing in of the application since its using  Sitefinity - Azure AD B2C Authentication and there are some values being passed in each requests such as nonce, state properties, id token etc. The workflow is quite complicated when having a peek into the values/token being passed across the requests of login. Though I have created/tried with all the values that are getting as the response of previous requests, still the login is not happening. Also, I went through  some documents of B2C authentication with Sitefinity and its architecture and I got to know that the token being generated by the Sitefinity is an internal process and the response of that token cannot be fetched from a previous response/ client side.

Workarounds that I did:

1. Integrated selenium into Jmeter and automated the login scenarios and stored the cookie generated. Then used these cookie and token in following internal requests- This approach worked fine.
   [image: Selenium- Jmeter for login]
2. Hardcoded a live cookie in Cookie Manager and send the internal requests - This also worked fine.

I am wondering if there is any other possibilities in logging in because the above two methods are not reliable in long run. Anyone have idea about generating the token id locally and pass that to JMeter. for example creating a .exe file which generates the Sitefinity token.With this we will be able to pass or execute the .exe file in OS Process Sampler in Jmeter and fetching the token from its response.

Or

Any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the **OpenIdConnect** authentication provider that is built into Sitefinity?

So, basically when a user clicks on the Login button, he is being redirected to:

/login/LoginExternalProvider/OpenIdConnect/

Here Sitefinity replies with a redirection to:

/Sitefinity/Authenticate/OpenID/connect/authorize?client_id=sitefinity&....

which in turn redirects to

/Sitefinity/Authenticate/OpenID/login?signin=....

and this finally redirects to the external authentication provider.

(yeah, it is a complex workflow).

So, if you try to load test only the first request (/login/LoginExternalProvider/OpenIdConnect/) - wouldn't it then follow the redirect responses automatically (sorry, not familiar with jmeter)?

Those responses contain the correct cookies that Sitefinity has created, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Sitefinity documentation](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/authentication-and-single-sign-on-(sso)):

> Sitefinity CMS uses claims authentication, implemented on top of IdentityServer3, certified by OpenID Foundation. It allows implementing single sign-on and access control for modern web applications and APIs. It uses OAuth2 and OpenID Connect protocols.

> Standardized authentication, based on OpenID Connect with JWT, certified IdentityServer3.

Given you're capable of logging in using your browser - you can replicate the same requests using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, it's just a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)  - the process of extracting the dynamic data from the responses and using them in the next requests.

You can refer [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for example JMeter script implementation